# Perl and parsing messy text

Tags: perl, parsing, unpack

I have the following text

```
                         Instructor First                          Number Students Who   Number Students Who
Subject Course Section                      Instructor Last Name                                               A    B C       D F
                         Name                                      Completed the Class   Dropped the Class
ACCT    201    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          56                    6                     19   9    16   2   5
ACCT    202    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          69                    11                    37   14   7    2   6
ACCT    205    01        Darryl             Woolley                20                    1                     3    7    6    1   3
ACCT    205    02        Darryl             Woolley                28                    1                     6    7    13       2
ACCT    205    03        Darryl             Woolley                42                    5                     4    13   21   1   3
ACCT    205    04        Darryl             Woolley                23                    1                     9    5    8    1
ACCT    205    05        Darryl             Woolley                30                    2                     11   7    9    2   1
ACCT    205    06        Darryl             Woolley                25                    3                     8    9    6    1   1
ACCT    275    01        Darryl             Woolley                33                    2                     7    15   9    1   1
ACCT    310    01        Marla              Kraut                  16                    1                     1    6    7    2
ACCT    310    02        Marla              Kraut                  64                                          5    43   15   1
ACCT    310    03        Marla              Kraut                  72                    3                     11   47   10   3   1
ACCT    311    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          45                                          13   20   11   1
ACCT    311    02        Karin              Hatheway Dial          25                                          10   12   3
ACCT    315    01        Jason              Porter                 26                                          6    5    8    6   1
ACCT    315    02        Jason              Porter                 29                    1                     6    10   5    7   1
ACCT    414    01        Teresa             Gordon                 22                    1                     6    6    9    1
ACCT    483    01        Glen               Utzman                 26                    1                     7    13   6
ACCT    486    01        Teresa             Gordon                 33                                          13   14   6
ACCT    492    01        Jason              Wills                  23                                          5    8    9    1
ACCT    515    01        Jeffrey            Harkins                15                                          7    6    1
ACCT    561    01        Jason              Porter                 18                    1                     10   7    1
ADOL    526    13        Charles            Gagel                  21                    2                     19   1             1
ADOL    573    13        Martha             Yopp                   28                                          16   3             1
ADOL    574    01        Laura              Holyoke                16                                          12   3             1
ADOL    574    11        Laura              Holyoke                9                     1                     8    1
ADOL    574    13        Laura              Holyoke                15                                          10   4             1
ADOL    600    13        Roger              Scott                  19                                          4         1
AERO    101    01        William            Beauter                11                                          8    2    1
AERO    103    01        Sarah              Babbitt                15                                          7    6    1        1
AERO    411    01        Sarah              Babbitt                11                                          6    4    1
AERO    413    01        Sarah              Babbitt                12                                          8    3    1
AGEC   101   01   Larry         Van Tassell   36    1    20   15        1
AGEC   278   01   Larry         Makus         21    1    2    6    8    5
AGEC   278   02   Larry         Makus         18         5    10   2    1
AGEC   278   03   Larry         Makus         17    1    2    7    5    2    1
AGEC   301   01   Christopher   McIntosh      18         9    4    5
AGEC   356   01   Joseph        Guenthner     23         15   6    2
AGEC   361   01   Ruby          Stroschein    11         4    1    6
AGEC   411   01   Robert        Haggerty      11         6    4    1
AGEC   413   01   Robert        Spear         12    3    4    5    2    1
AGEC   415   01   Larry         Van Tassell   11         10   1
AGEC   526   01   Scott         Matulich      7          2    5
AGEC   527   01   Stephen       Cooke         5          3    2
AGED   180   01   Lori          Moore         23    1    14   5    1    3
AGED   351   01   Lou           Riesenberg    11         4    6    1
AMST   301   01   Walter        Hesford       26         14   8    3         1
ANTH   100   01   Mark          Warner        104   15   31   31   21   8    12
ANTH   220   01   Fumiyasu      Arakawa       138   4    48   53   19   10   8
ANTH   230   01   Robert        Sappington    28    1    7    9    9    2    1
ANTH   251   01   Donald        Tyler         36    1    10   14   8    1    3
ANTH   420   01   Laura         Putsche       12         3    4    2         2
ANTH   422   01   Rodney        Frey          13         11                  2
ANTH   427   02   Virginia      Babcock       13    1         2    6 4       1
ANTH   462   01   Laura         Putsche       33    3    8    20   3 1
ARBC   101   01   Anisah        El-Mansouri   14    1    8    5    1
ARCH   151   01   Randall       Teal          150   8    72   40   13 6      19
ARCH   253   01   Roman         Montoto       23    1    9    10   2         1
ARCH   253   02   Randall       Teal          22    2    9    11   2
ARCH   253   03   Xiao          Hu            23    2    11   12
ARCH   353   01   Matthew       Brehm         16         7    7    1
ARCH   353   02   Dillon        Ellefson      16         4    11   1
ARCH   353   03   Xiao          Hu            10         4    6
ARCH   385   01   Anne          Marshall      68    5    29   22   11 2      4
ARCH   404   04   Matthew       Brehm         10         1    5    3 1
ARCH   453   01   Roman         Montoto       10         5    4    1
ARCH   453   02   Anne       Marshall              13        6     5             1
ARCH   463   01   Phillip    Mead                  63    1   26    31   5 1
ARCH   465   01   Kenneth    Carper                51    1   8     26   12 3
ARCH   483   01   D.         Reese                 71    2   27    35   8
ARCH   504   02   Randall    Teal                  15        9     6
ARCH   504   03   Kevin      Van Den Wymelenberg   6         3     1             1
ARCH   504   04   Frank      Jacobus               12    1   8     4
ARCH   510   02   D.         Reese                 13        9     4
ARCH   510   04   Robert     Thornton              9         7     1
ARCH   510   05   Roman      Montoto               11    2   7     4
ARCH   553   01   Bruce      Haglund               14        12    2
```

I have this code / sub which gets each line and suppose to produce a relevant list:

```
sub GetData {

    my $non_nor_line              = shift;
    my( $subj, $crs,$sec, $rest ) = unpack "a6 a6 a6 a*", $non_nor_line;
    my $name                      = undef;
    my $upk_short  = q{A3A2A3A2 A3A2 A3AA5 A6};





    $rest =~ m/(.+?)\d/;
    $name = $1;
    $rest =~ s/$1//;
    $rest =~ s/^\s+//;
    $rest =~ s/\s+$//;
    my @rest_data                 = unpack($upk_short,$rest);    


    print $_ ."\n" foreach(@rest_data);


}
```

I have no idea how to get the data from the $rest, I tried many variations with unpack but to no avail, I need to store it into a list.
ignore 'upk_short', its incorrect, although I tried many others, seems like the lines are too dynamic.

**UPDATE**: It would be fine if someone can find a way to normalize the text, by which I mean to align everything so that I can use Tom's way to parse it.

Any idea?

Comment: Just a minute, and I'll show you how to **always** get these `unpack` things right the firt time, *every* time.

Comment: Been reading about unpack for hours now, I do know (I guess) how to use it, and what each A,W etc... says, still I cant figure out a way to parse it.

Comment: There you go.  Please tell me whether that helps.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot. secondly, it does what it needs to, the only problem I am facing now is the alignment (my data is not normalized, as you said....) and I cant find a way to normalize it. the data was extracted from a pdf, using: pdftotext --nopgbrk --layout, I also tried expand and even sed to replace \t+ with single space,nothing

Comment: It can't be *impossible* to normalize. Maybe you need to substitute all whitespace to single space?

Comment: Oh, gosh, I *hate* scraping pdf2text converters; it’s always cruddy. I guess what you might do is separate the run of numbers from everything else. The first part could just be split on `\h+`. Then the numbers portion you would be more careful with and split on perhaps `\h{1,3}` or so. That would let you get some empty fields. I’m just not sure you can count on that—in which case you would have to gather adjacent lines with duplicate starting places and infer columns from that sample. Terrible mess, really.

Comment: @Jefromi   but then I will ignore empty fields.

Comment: @tchrist         I tried, still no go, and I keep trying. thanks

Comment: @tchrist   and I did separate the numbers from the rest, this is what my code above does in the first place

Comment: Well, I came to a conclusion, as you already mentioned, that I need to first align the data, but I have no idea how. pdftotext seems to change the alignment for each page, although its not like that in the original pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data looks strangely formatted, are there tabs in there? It looks like three sets of records, each set having a different layout - is that correct?

If the data is in fixed positions, unpacking all twelve columns at once ought to be possible. If there are three types of layout, I'd use a regex to decide which layout applies to the current line, then use an appropriate template for that group of records.

Since some of the twelve data columns can be blank and some records have numbers in anomalous positions, it may be impossible to ascribe some values to the correct column.

---

EDIT

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @heading = qw(Subject Course Section Firstname Lastname
                 Completed Dropped A B C D F);

# Use position of Instructors Last Name as a guide to line layout.
my %template = (45 => "A8 A7 A10 A19 A23 A22 A22 A5 A5 A5 A4 A4",
                33 => "A7 A6 A5  A14 A14 A6  A5  A5 A5 A5 A5 A5",
                30 => "A7 A6 A5  A11 A22 A6  A4  A6 A5 A2 A2 A2");

while(<DATA>) {
  next unless /^[A-Z]{4} /;
  chomp;
  GetData($_);
}

sub GetData {
  my $line = shift;
  for my $lastname_position (keys %template) {
    if (substr($line, $lastname_position-2, 2) =~ / [A-Z]/) {
      my @values = unpack ($template{$lastname_position}, $line);
      my $column=0;
      for my $value(@values) {
        print "$heading[$column] = '$value'\n";
        $column++;
      }
      print "\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
                         Instructor First                          Number Students Who   Number Students Who
Subject Course Section                      Instructor Last Name                                               A    B C       D F
                         Name                                      Completed the Class   Dropped the Class
ACCT    201    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          56                    6                     19   9    16   2   5
ACCT    202    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          69                    11                    37   14   7    2   6
ACCT    205    01        Darryl             Woolley                20                    1                     3    7    6    1   3
ACCT    205    02        Darryl             Woolley                28                    1                     6    7    13       2
ACCT    205    03        Darryl             Woolley                42                    5                     4    13   21   1   3
ACCT    205    04        Darryl             Woolley                23                    1                     9    5    8    1
ACCT    205    05        Darryl             Woolley                30                    2                     11   7    9    2   1
ACCT    205    06        Darryl             Woolley                25                    3                     8    9    6    1   1
ACCT    275    01        Darryl             Woolley                33                    2                     7    15   9    1   1
ACCT    310    01        Marla              Kraut                  16                    1                     1    6    7    2
ACCT    310    02        Marla              Kraut                  64                                          5    43   15   1
ACCT    310    03        Marla              Kraut                  72                    3                     11   47   10   3   1
ACCT    311    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          45                                          13   20   11   1
ACCT    311    02        Karin              Hatheway Dial          25                                          10   12   3
ACCT    315    01        Jason              Porter                 26                                          6    5    8    6   1
ACCT    315    02        Jason              Porter                 29                    1                     6    10   5    7   1
ACCT    414    01        Teresa             Gordon                 22                    1                     6    6    9    1
ACCT    483    01        Glen               Utzman                 26                    1                     7    13   6
ACCT    486    01        Teresa             Gordon                 33                                          13   14   6
ACCT    492    01        Jason              Wills                  23                                          5    8    9    1
ACCT    515    01        Jeffrey            Harkins                15                                          7    6    1
ACCT    561    01        Jason              Porter                 18                    1                     10   7    1
ADOL    526    13        Charles            Gagel                  21                    2                     19   1             1
ADOL    573    13        Martha             Yopp                   28                                          16   3             1
ADOL    574    01        Laura              Holyoke                16                                          12   3             1
ADOL    574    11        Laura              Holyoke                9                     1                     8    1
ADOL    574    13        Laura              Holyoke                15                                          10   4             1
ADOL    600    13        Roger              Scott                  19                                          4         1
AERO    101    01        William            Beauter                11                                          8    2    1
AERO    103    01        Sarah              Babbitt                15                                          7    6    1        1
AERO    411    01        Sarah              Babbitt                11                                          6    4    1
AERO    413    01        Sarah              Babbitt                12                                          8    3    1
AGEC   101   01   Larry         Van Tassell   36    1    20   15        1
AGEC   278   01   Larry         Makus         21    1    2    6    8    5
AGEC   278   02   Larry         Makus         18         5    10   2    1
AGEC   278   03   Larry         Makus         17    1    2    7    5    2    1
AGEC   301   01   Christopher   McIntosh      18         9    4    5
AGEC   356   01   Joseph        Guenthner     23         15   6    2
AGEC   361   01   Ruby          Stroschein    11         4    1    6
AGEC   411   01   Robert        Haggerty      11         6    4    1
AGEC   413   01   Robert        Spear         12    3    4    5    2    1
AGEC   415   01   Larry         Van Tassell   11         10   1
AGEC   526   01   Scott         Matulich      7          2    5
AGEC   527   01   Stephen       Cooke         5          3    2
AGED   180   01   Lori          Moore         23    1    14   5    1    3
AGED   351   01   Lou           Riesenberg    11         4    6    1
AMST   301   01   Walter        Hesford       26         14   8    3         1
ANTH   100   01   Mark          Warner        104   15   31   31   21   8    12
ANTH   220   01   Fumiyasu      Arakawa       138   4    48   53   19   10   8
ANTH   230   01   Robert        Sappington    28    1    7    9    9    2    1
ANTH   251   01   Donald        Tyler         36    1    10   14   8    1    3
ANTH   420   01   Laura         Putsche       12         3    4    2         2
ANTH   422   01   Rodney        Frey          13         11                  2
ANTH   427   02   Virginia      Babcock       13    1         2    6 4       1
ANTH   462   01   Laura         Putsche       33    3    8    20   3 1
ARBC   101   01   Anisah        El-Mansouri   14    1    8    5    1
ARCH   151   01   Randall       Teal          150   8    72   40   13 6      19
ARCH   253   01   Roman         Montoto       23    1    9    10   2         1
ARCH   253   02   Randall       Teal          22    2    9    11   2
ARCH   253   03   Xiao          Hu            23    2    11   12
ARCH   353   01   Matthew       Brehm         16         7    7    1
ARCH   353   02   Dillon        Ellefson      16         4    11   1
ARCH   353   03   Xiao          Hu            10         4    6
ARCH   385   01   Anne          Marshall      68    5    29   22   11 2      4
ARCH   404   04   Matthew       Brehm         10         1    5    3 1
ARCH   453   01   Roman         Montoto       10         5    4    1
ARCH   453   02   Anne       Marshall              13        6     5             1
ARCH   463   01   Phillip    Mead                  63    1   26    31   5 1
ARCH   465   01   Kenneth    Carper                51    1   8     26   12 3
ARCH   483   01   D.         Reese                 71    2   27    35   8
ARCH   504   02   Randall    Teal                  15        9     6
ARCH   504   03   Kevin      Van Den Wymelenberg   6         3     1             1
ARCH   504   04   Frank      Jacobus               12    1   8     4
ARCH   510   02   D.         Reese                 13        9     4
ARCH   510   04   Robert     Thornton              9         7     1
ARCH   510   05   Roman      Montoto               11    2   7     4
ARCH   553   01   Bruce      Haglund               14        12    2
```

Output

```
Subject = 'ACCT'
Course = '201'
Section = '01'
Firstname = 'Karin'
Lastname = 'Hatheway Dial'
Completed = '56'
Dropped = '6'
A = '19'
B = '9'
C = '16'
D = '2'
F = '5'
```

...

```
Subject = 'AGEC'
Course = '101'
Section = '01'
Firstname = 'Larry'
Lastname = 'Van Tassell'
Completed = '36'
Dropped = '1'
A = '20'
B = '15'
C = ''
D = '1'
F = ''
```

...

```
Subject = 'ARCH'
Course = '553'
Section = '01'
Firstname = 'Bruce'
Lastname = 'Haglund'
Completed = '14'
Dropped = ''
A = '12'
B = '2'
C = ''
D = ''
F = ''
```

But the data really needs to be cleaner.

Comment: No, `unpack` is the correct function for this, **not** `substr`.

Comment: This is an exact 'copy & paste' from my text file, I've tried many combinations of unpack but with no success. actually, I managed, as you can see, to extract anything in the way I want until '...Completed the Class' column, since the rest of the columns can be blank, that what makes my life harder.

Comment: Actually, if there were some anchors instead of empty fields I could do this with unpack. Thanks

Comment: @tchrist (re substr) answer amended accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub cut2fmt {
    my @positions  = @_;
    my $template   = "";
    my $lastpos    = 1;
    for my $place (@positions) {
        $template .= "A" . ($place - $lastpos) . " ";
        $lastpos   = $place;
    }
    $template .= "A*";
    return $template;
}

my $fmt = cut2fmt(9, 16, 26, 45, 68, 90, 112, 117, 122, 127, 131);

my @keys = qw{

    subject                 course              section

    instructor_first_name   instructor_last_name

    completed_the_class     dropped_the_class

    grade_A                 grade_B
    grade_C                 grade_D
    grade_F

};

our @All_Records;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if 1 .. /^\s*\|/;
    my %rec;
    @rec{@keys} = unpack($fmt, $_);
    for my $key (grep { /^grade_[A-F]$/ } @keys) {
        $rec{$key} ||= 0;
    }
    push @All_Records, \%rec;
}

for my $rec (@All_Records) {
    for my $key (@keys) {
        print "$key: $rec->{$key}\n";
    }
    print "\n";

}

__END__
Subject Course Section                      Instructor Last Name                                               A    B C       D F
                         Name                                      Completed the Class   Dropped the Class
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0         1         2         3         4
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        |      |         |                  |                      |                     |                     |    |    |    |   |
ACCT    201    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          56                    6                     19   9    16   2   5
ACCT    202    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          69                    11                    37   14   7    2   6
ACCT    205    01        Darryl             Woolley                20                    1                     3    7    6    1   3
ACCT    205    02        Darryl             Woolley                28                    1                     6    7    13       2
ACCT    205    03        Darryl             Woolley                42                    5                     4    13   21   1   3
ACCT    205    04        Darryl             Woolley                23                    1                     9    5    8    1
ACCT    205    05        Darryl             Woolley                30                    2                     11   7    9    2   1
ACCT    205    06        Darryl             Woolley                25                    3                     8    9    6    1   1
ACCT    275    01        Darryl             Woolley                33                    2                     7    15   9    1   1
ACCT    310    01        Marla              Kraut                  16                    1                     1    6    7    2
ACCT    310    02        Marla              Kraut                  64                                          5    43   15   1
ACCT    310    03        Marla              Kraut                  72                    3                     11   47   10   3   1
ACCT    311    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          45                                          13   20   11   1
ACCT    311    02        Karin              Hatheway Dial          25                                          10   12   3
ACCT    315    01        Jason              Porter                 26                                          6    5    8    6   1
ACCT    315    02        Jason              Porter                 29                    1                     6    10   5    7   1
ACCT    414    01        Teresa             Gordon                 22                    1                     6    6    9    1
ACCT    483    01        Glen               Utzman                 26                    1                     7    13   6
ACCT    486    01        Teresa             Gordon                 33                                          13   14   6
ACCT    492    01        Jason              Wills                  23                                          5    8    9    1
ACCT    515    01        Jeffrey            Harkins                15                                          7    6    1
ACCT    561    01        Jason              Porter                 18                    1                     10   7    1
ADOL    526    13        Charles            Gagel                  21                    2                     19   1             1
ADOL    573    13        Martha             Yopp                   28                                          16   3             1
ADOL    574    01        Laura              Holyoke                16                                          12   3             1
ADOL    574    11        Laura              Holyoke                9                     1                     8    1
ADOL    574    13        Laura              Holyoke                15                                          10   4             1
ADOL    600    13        Roger              Scott                  19                                          4         1
AERO    101    01        William            Beauter                11                                          8    2    1
AERO    103    01        Sarah              Babbitt                15                                          7    6    1        1
AERO    411    01        Sarah              Babbitt                11                                          6    4    1
AERO    413    01        Sarah              Babbitt                12                                          8    3    1
```

The first thing you have to do is normalize your data.  Your columns are inconsistent, and I can't tell you why that might be. Perhaps you have tabs that need being piped through `expand -8` or something.  I only include the data that is all of the same alignment.

To get your `unpack` format right every time, you just need to draw a numbered ruler like I have right under it.  Put a `|` mark right where each field starts.  Record that number, and pass it off to the included `cut2fmt()` function. It will turn those numbers into a `pack/unpack` template.

That’s all there is to it.

I *would* tell you where to come by such nuggets, but I just **hate** pushy self-promoters, so it would be hypocritical of my to stoop so low.  I won’t do it. If somebody wants to advertise, fine, let them buy spamverts from the site.  Then those of us who loathe spamvertising can block with our ad-blockers. Otherwise it’s just unseemly for me to stomach.

Comment: What's with the `our`? Does it have any added benefit over `my` in this situation?

Comment: Hi, Greg. Zaid, the `our` is because it’s a global; that’s why it’s capped.  So is the `$fmt`, too, really. I try to limit the scope of `my` variables, give them short names and such. Things at file scope may be different, but it’s hard to show that sort of consistency with small examples.